# На что заменить словарь Dictionary<string,object> чтобы избавится от Boxing (C# netcore2.2)

Tags: c#, .net-core

Достался проект на поддержку, и после решения насущных проблем, пришло время рефакторинга. 
В одном из основных методов происходит Boxing, этот метод крутится на бекграунде для многих потоков (по экземпляру на поток, без concurrency).

имею метод для замены подстрок по шаблону.

```
 public static (string resultStr, Dictionary<string,object> resultInsearts) InsertByTemplate(string template, Dictionary<string,object> insearts, string pattern = @"\{(.*?)(:.+?)?\}")
 {
    string Evaluator(Match match)
    {           
       // В insearts по ключу находится значение для замены и возвращается.
        return res;
    }
    var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, Evaluator);
 }
```

В передаваемом словаре `insearts` содержатся все варианты вставок (около 200 значений) 
 Возвращаемый в кортеже словарь `resultInsearts` содержит только РЕАЛЬНО вставленные значения.
 Наиболее используемые типы в cловаре это `string, int, DateTime.`
 Т.е. `Boxing`  `struct->object` происходит часто и при формировании словаря `insearts` и еще при формировании `resultInsearts`.

для тестов быстренько заменил словарь на

```
public class IndependentInserts
{
    #region field
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _strDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, int> _intDict= new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, DateTime> _dateTimeDict  = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    #endregion


    #region Methode
    public bool TryAddValue(string key, int value)
    {
        return _intDict.TryAdd(key, value);
    }
    public bool TryAddValue(string key, string value)
    {
        return _strDict.TryAdd(key, value);
    }
    public bool TryAddValue(string key, DateTime value)
    {
        return _dateTimeDict.TryAdd(key, value);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out int value)
    {
        return _intDict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out string value)
    {
        return _strDict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out DateTime value)
    {
        return _dateTimeDict.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }


    public Dictionary<string, object> Map2BoxeDictionary() //Вызывается редко по запросу пользователя
    {
        var boxeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var (key, value) in _strDict)
        {
            boxeDictionary[key] = value;
        }
        foreach (var (key, value) in _intDict)
        {
            boxeDictionary[key] = value;
        }
        foreach (var (key, value) in _dateTimeDict)
        {
            boxeDictionary[key] = value;
        }
        return boxeDictionary;
    }
    #endregion
}


public static (string resultStr, IndependentInserts resultInsearts) InsertByTemplate(string template, IndependentInserts insearts, string pattern = @"\{(.*?)(:.+?)?\}")
{
    var resultInsearts = new IndependentInserts(); 
    string Evaluator(Match match)
    {
        string res = null;
        var key = match.Groups[1].Value;

        if (inserts.TryGetValue(key, out string strVal))                 //обработка string значений
        {

        }
        else
        if (inserts.TryGetValue(key, out DateTime dateTimeVal))          //обработка DateTime значений
        {

        }
        else    
        if (inserts.TryGetValue(key, out int intVal))                    //обработка int значений
        {

        }
        else
        if (key.Contains("rowNumber"))                                  //обработка служебных значений
        {

        }
        else
        {
            res = match.Value;
        }
        return res;
    }

    var result = Regex.Replace(template, pattern, Evaluator);
    return (result, resultInsearts);
}
```

С добавлением элементов все хорошо, `TryAddValue` вызовет нужный метод по перегрузке. 
А вот `TryGetValue` нужно вызывать для каждого типа и проверять в каком же словаре находится подставляемое значение.

Хотел обсудить как бы кто поступил для замены Dictionary?

Пояснения к коду:
для вызова метода `InsertByTemplate` внешний код создает словарь `Dictionary<string,object> insearts`. Где ключ это строка под замену, а `value` это значение замены. `value` это `object` - и в него помешается как ссылочный тип string,  так и структуры `int, DateTime`. Алгоритм метода `InsertByTemplate`: это поиск в строке паттерна (через regex) и замена найденной подстроки на значение из словаря.

Comment: вы ни задачу не рассказали, ни алгоритм свой не пояснили, ни проблему не раскрыли. Какие тут могут быть рекомендации?\

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: добавил пояснение к работе метода InsertByTemplate. Специально не стал писать весь код работы метода, чтобы не отвлекать от сути вопроса. Суть  вопроса в том что метод принимает  Dictionary<string,object> и мне кажется это плохо если я знаю что под object передаются ValueType

Comment: @Aldmi, решается заменой object на string

Comment: Вот я про то же. У вас походу XY проблема. Смысл хранить int, datetime когда вы в итоге их к строке приводите.

Comment: Формат приведения к строке находится в самой форматной строке, то есть "{Time:t} - переменную Time надо заменить на строку в формате t. Да и вообще хотелось бы иметь не строки в этих обработчиках, мало ли что еще понадобится при рефакторинге. P.S. извиняюсь что не точно описал алгортим

Comment: можете описать, в чем проблема с боксингом? Ну есть у вас боксинг, как именно вы от этого страдаете? Памяти много ест? Или медленно работает?

Comment: В профилировщике заметил, что основное кол-во новых объектов связанно с этими подстановками, на самом деле не критично, GC вызывается редко, память не утекает. Но сам вопрос мне показался интересным, вдруг это будет в критически важном месте.

Comment: Эта программа это сервис опроса оборудования для Scada систем, сейчас более 300 паралельно работающих устройств не опрашивается и время на ответ 300мс самое малое. Но если будут более быстрые устройства и их кол-во возрастет. Поэтому и  занялся рефакторингом критически важных мест

Comment: но вы тут по любому будете создавать объекты, каждое форматирование или каждый `Regex.Replace` создают новую строку. Можно конечно тут придумать и неизменяемый класс типа `ValueHolder<T>` и кешировать форматированные значения, но, имхо, пока это не прблема, я бы не стал это трогать.

Comment: Regex.Replace  - уйдет, алгоритм переработаю и будет StringBuilder.Replace(). Как раз таки хочу закешировать возможные значения создав объект в котором находится: Строка под замену, ее формат, значение замены, и в Реалтайме будет меняться только  значение замены и подставятся это будет через StringBuilder.Replace().

Comment: Моя реализация "в лоб" (3 словаря) IndependentInserts в принципе меня устраивает, но вот использование TryGetValue совсем не нравится)

Comment: Мне кажется, короткий комментарий Grundy является правильным решением. В любом случае типы int и DateTime будут преобразованы в строку, когда они будут использоваться для замены. Поэтому можно их конвертировать в string при помещении в словарь.

Comment: Важно ли сохранить информацию о _типах_ в resultInsearts?

Comment: resultInsearts - думаю не важно сохранение типов, но основная проблема в том подстановка выполняется по формату и формат находится в самой строке, то есть "какая-то строка{nubmerOfTrain:X2}", подразумевается что nubmerOfTrain будет int и вставится по формату X2 "какая-то строка0x02" если nubmerOfTrain =2.

Comment: Я понимаю что со строкой самый лучший вариант, Попробую сделать разбор форматной строки до преобразования и этот объект закеширую, чтобы потом только значения по формату подставлять. Попытаюсь не в ущерб функционалу хранить сразу строковое значение. Всем спасибо за обсуждения!!